# Widgets are not clickeable (QT designer)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been trying to make GUI but my biggest problem right now is that any of the buttons are clickable, even if I code an action for them, and as you can see in this picture, I can't select numbers in the spin boxes either

[image: picture]

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `frame_3` widget has its `enabled` property not set. Therefore everything it contains is also not enabled, i.e. grayed out.

Since `frame_3` is nested in other widgets the actual problem (the first widget that is not `enabled`) might be further up in the tree.